# Problema al importar libreria Javascript a mi proyecto

Tags: javascript

hoy tengo un problema al intentar utilizar una libreria Javascript en mi proyecto,la libreria en cuestion es Anime.js, al entrar a su sitio web y luego en "Download" te da instrucciones para utilizar la libreria, y aun despues de utilizar el metodo para instalar la libreria de la etiqueta "Script" en tu html con el atributo "src" a el archivo en cuestion no puedo utilizar la libreria en mi archivo javascript, ya probe poner el link en el head de la pagina, probe ponerlo antes de mi script y despues, nada funciona, simplemente intento llamar a la funcion "anime()" de la lib y no ocurre nada como si no existiera.Espero puedan ayudarme y gracias.

Comment: Hola amigo, para poder ayudarte con tu problema es necesario que proporciones más información sobre el mismo, te aconsejo leer en [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) luego adita y mejora tu pregunta :D

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: @Josbert hola buenos dias, la verdad no veo como mi pregunta esta mal formulada, estoy diciendo lo mas claramente posible que estoy colocando una etiqueta script que linkea a una libreria javascript con mi proyecto y que dicha libreria no esta siendo importada. No veo como puedo agregar mas detalles, es un problema simple, estoy haciendo esto que se supone que funciona, y no esta funcionando. Que tengas buen dia.